Bind to an optional variable within a view model
I have the following view model that contains an optional property - parentList: TodoList. Not all todo lists will have a parent, while some can so I use an optional to represent this both in the view model and in the @Model itself.
@Observable
class TodoListEditorViewModel: Validatable {
    var name: String
    var color: Color
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var kind: TodoList.TodoListKind
    var parentList: TodoList?
    
    init(name: String, color: Color, isFavorite: Bool, kind: TodoList.TodoListKind, parentList: TodoList?) {
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.isFavorite = isFavorite
        self.kind = kind
        self.parentList = parentList
        parent = TodoList(name: "")
    }
}


I have a View with a form that is used to edit the properties of the view model. In the form, I navigate to a child view for the parentList property that displays a lists of TodoLists available for the user to pick from. The user would pick one and it would get assigned to the view model parentList or they can cancel and return to the form. When the user is finished it can save a model as a stand-alone list, or as a nested list because it has a parent.

struct TodoListEditorForm: View {
    
    @Bindable var viewModel: TodoListEditorViewModel
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Name", text: $viewModel.name)
                }
                
                Section {
                    NavigationLink {
                        TodoListPicker(viewModel: $viewModel)
                    } label: {
                        ColorizedLabel(iconColor: $viewModel.color, title: "Parent List", icon: IconConstants.listIcon)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct TodoListPicker: View {
    @Query private var todoLists: [TodoList]
    @State var selectedTodoList: TodoList
    @Bindable var viewModel: TodoListEditorViewModel
    

    var body: some View {
        List(todoLists) { list in
            Text(list.name)
        }
    }
}

When I try to pass the binding of the parentList into the child view, I get a compiler error saying:

Cannot convert value '$viewModel' of type 'Bindable' to expected type 'TodoListEditorViewModel', use wrapped value instead

I create the TodoList in the parent view of the TodoListEditorForm as a @State property and pass it in as a bindable.
struct TodoListEditorView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @Bindable private var editingList: TodoList
    
    let isNewTodoList: Bool
    
    @State private var viewModel: TodoListEditorViewModel
    
    init() {
        isNewTodoList = true
        editingList = TodoList(name: String())
        viewModel = TodoListEditorViewModel(
            name: "",
            color: .accent,
            isFavorite: false,
            kind: .basic,
            parentList: nil)
    }
    
    init(editingList: TodoList) {
        self.editingList = editingList
        isNewTodoList = false
        viewModel = TodoListEditorViewModel(
            name: editingList.name,
            color: editingList.colorValue,
            isFavorite: editingList.isFavorite,
            kind: editingList.kind,
            parentList: editingList.parentTodoList)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TodoListEditorForm(viewModel: viewModel)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                        Button("Cancel") {
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(viewModel.color)
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                        Button("Done") {
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(viewModel.color)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}


How would I go about setting this property in SwiftUI and maintain the binding?

If you want to keep the @Bindable var viewModel: TodoListEditorViewModel as is in ToDoListPicker, then you need to pass it what it expects - an observable object of type TodoListEditorViewModel, which is the  (wrapped) value of the binding you created in TodoListEditorForm. So change your call to: TodoListPicker(viewModel: $viewModel.wrappedValue). I think this will work, although I am not sure it's intended to be used like this.

I lose the binding if I pass the unwrapped value, don't I? I'd rather change my design to align with best practices in this scenario while maintaining the binding capabilities. if I need to do some abstracting, I can do that but I'm not sure what that looks like in SwiftUI and SwiftData as these are newer frameworks for me

So TodoListEditorViewModel is an observed class that will not be persisted but TodoList is a @Model class that is persisted by SwiftData, is that correct?

Correct. In my save code (not shown) it transfers the data from the viewmodel property into a model and inserts it into the modelContext which then updates my @Query properties elsewhere in the app. This seems to be resolved by passing the bindable directly to the child view like: TodoListPicker(viewModel: self.viewModel) rather than self.$viewModel. Will changes to the view model in the child view publish to the parent view if I pass it in like this?

What I don't really get is where is your  TodoListEditorViewModel instance created? Does TodoListEditorForm also receive the viewModel from its parent?

Yes, there is a TodoListEditor view with a property. I updated my question to show that View and how the view model is created.

I a, not sure I fully understand but what about not passing the view model into the TodoListPicker but instead a TodoList property and then update the view model in an onChange modifier for this new property?

I'll look at that. I eventually got it to work by removing the $ and just passing the viewmodel as-is, which I didn't realize was already a binding when declared with @State
